# What's does \e901 mean for the CSS content tag?

Tags: css, svg

In our CSS file I see this:

```
[class*="iconsmall-"]:before {
  font-family: 'icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  speak: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
          font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
} 

.iconsmall-unknown:before {content: '\e901';}
```

We have an unknown .svg file.  What does \e901 mean and how does it know that its the unknown.svg file being referenced?

I will a similar situation here with this Code Pen:

https://codepen.io/bungeedesign/pen/XqeLQg with \f003 being referenced.

Comment: read about how fonts workss ... and these aren't always SVG

Comment: thats the unicode character of the glyph from the icon font being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\` indicates a Unicode character reference follows.  Consisting of four hex digits.

The [e901 character code](https://unicode-table.com/en/E901/) is part of a block reserved for private use.  And is probably assigned to a particular glyph in the font being used there.  I am guessing it is an icon font.

[f003](https://unicode-table.com/en/F003/) is the same.  That CodePen is using the FontAwesome font, and we can see from the FA docs that it corresponds (as expected) to the [envelope icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/envelope-o).

Comment: The private use thing makes the most sense.  https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/private-use-area/

Comment: I went to our internal icon site and all the icons have a private use unicode tag as well.    Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The CSS property `content` can be used to display text, images and SVG code. The `\` is a way to "escape" special chars and show specific characters of a font. The `\` is always followed by the unicode. In your example it is e901 
Usage:

```
.hello::before { content: "world" } // shows world
.hello::before { content: url('/assets/icons/icon.svg') } // shows a SVG image
.hello::before { content: "\u2663"} // shows ♣ (instead of "\u2663")
```

More examples: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Have fun!